# nginx reverse proxy to serve two docker containers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have two docker containers 1) shiny R app, 2) python flask api app. I want to use nginx as a front-end reverse proxy and serve both using the same port number (80). I simply want the main url (`localhost:1337`) go to the shiny app GUI, whereas `localhost:1337/api` would go to the python flask container. I'm not sure if it's possible. I based my `nginx.conf` file on this website: [How to bind multiple domains (ports 80 and 443) to docker contained applications](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-bind-multiple-domains-ports-80-and-443-to-docker-contained-applications), but I am only able to access the shiny app at `localhost:1337`. How can I access the python api by simply tagging on the `/api`? Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
# declare flask app
upstream pyapi_app {
    server pyapi:5000;
}

# declare shiny app
upstream shiny_app {
    server shinyapp:3838;
}

# shinyapp server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name shinyapp;

    # normal requests go to shiny app
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://shiny_app;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    }
}

# python api server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pyapi;

    # pyapi requests go to the flask app
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://pyapi_app;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    } 
}
```